# How to dynamically remove items from ListView on a button click?

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an app that requires removing items from a `ListView` on a button event.

I tried to remove it from `ArrayList` and create the whole new adapter and load the list again. As my list is huge, doing this will affect the performance of my app. So I was wondering if there is any other way by which I could remove an item from my list dynamically.

**Edit:** I tried what you said.

When I removed one item it worked perfectly, but as I increase the number of selected items it starts giving me IndexOutOfBoundException.

Here's my code:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = new SparseBooleanArray();
    checkedPositions.clear();
    checkedPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int size = checkedPositions.size();
    if(size != 0)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        {
            if(checkedPositions.valueAt(i))
            {
                list.remove(notes.getItem(checkedPositions.keyAt(i)));
                notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
        else{}
}
```

Here, `notes` is a reference to an object of SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well you just remove the desired item from the list using the `remove()` method of your `ArrayAdapter`.

A possible way to do that would be:

```
Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
```

Another way would be to modify the `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you have to add arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Well if you work with the `ArrayAdapter` directly you don't have to but if you work with the `ArrayList` you have to.

Comment: unfortunately i am using SimpleAdapter instead of ArrayadAdapter. so is there any way to remove item from SimpleAdapter like the way u mentioned above? or do i need to use ArrayAdapter insted of SimpleAdapter?

Comment: `ArrayList` is a concrete class whereas `List` is the interface. You can't instantiate a `List` but only a type implementing it. I'm quite certain you are working with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: the first way can only remove the last item, why?

Comment: How to I delete the selected item data from database. I used `ArrayAdapter`. I'm able to delete the item from the ListView and when I come back to my app again the deleted items are appeared again.

Comment: solution 1 worked for me.. I also called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after that.. The  simple logic is before you update the adapter you need to remove the item because listview does not know that you delete from db because `setAdapter` is called in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Hope it helps someone. :)

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) getListAdapter();
this.resultsList.remove((int) info.id);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
adapter.remove(arraylist.get(position));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or you can call again

```
setListAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Why should he do that in the `getView()` method?

Comment: (its not must) If he wanna remove item at position..or else if he wanna remove at statically he can use anywhere..

Comment: I think you got dynamically and statically mixed up now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a button on list and let it onclick feature in xml like to get postion first

```
public void OnClickButton(View V){
  final int postion = listView.getPositionForView(V);
    System.out.println("postion selected is : "+postion);
Delete(postion);

}
public void Delete(int position){
    if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {

        //Log.d("largest no is",""+largestitemno);
        //deleting the latest added by subtracting one 1 
        comment = (GenrricStoring) adapter.getItem(position);
        //Log.d("Deleting item is: ",""+comment);
        dbconnection.deleteComment(comment);
        List<GenrricStoring> values = dbconnection.getAllComments();
        //updating the content on the screen
        this.adapter = new UserItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else
    {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        //for showing nothing is left in the list
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Db is empty", duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<DataValue> datavalue=new ArrayList<Datavalue>;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datavalue.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String> entries;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> categoryAdapter;
 //Your list of entries {Example: <"category1","category2","category3">}
 entries =  new ArrayList<String>();
 categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewBeaconsActivity.this,
                                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entries);
 //Remove that specific category from the list
 entries.remove(categoryName);
 //Notify the adapter that your dataset has changed.
 categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove item from list view like this: 
or you can choose on your Button event which item have to be removed

```
public class Third extends ListActivity {
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private List<String> liste;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
     String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
     liste = new ArrayList<String>();
     Collections.addAll(liste, values);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
     setListAdapter(adapter);
}
 @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     liste.remove(position);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your last question, here's the problem illustrated with a simple example:

Let's say that your list contains 5 elements: `list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and your list of items to remove (i.e. the indices) is `indices_to_remove = [0, 2, 4]`. In the first iteration of the loop you remove the item at index 0, so your list becomes `list = [2, 3, 4, 5]`. In the second iteration, you remove the item at index 2, so your list becomes `list = [2, 3, 5]` (as you can see, this removes the wrong element). Finally, in the third iteration, you try to remove the element at index 4, but the list only contains three elements, so you get an out of bounds exception.

Now that you see what the problem is, hopefully you will be able to come up with a solution. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTipo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_clear"
    android:onClick="item_delete_handler"/>
```

*And create Event item_delete_handler*,