# How to get Hashmap of Arraylist Extra from previous intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I put hashmap of arraylist extra in old intent (SaleActivity)

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(SaleActivity.this,UpdateActivity.class);
newActivity.putExtra("saleArrList", saleArrList);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Then, I get it from newactivity (UpdateActivity)

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> saleArrList = intent.get...Extra("saleArrList");
```

What code in ... ,that i should use. Thanks for all answer a lots.

Comment: You say "hashmap of arraylist", but the code shows an arraylist of hashmaps.

Comment: @TedHopp what is difference b/w " hashmap of arrayList" and "arraylist of Hashmap" ???

Comment: @HashirAnwaar - The data are organized in completely different ways. In the first case, you hand me a key and you get back an `ArrayList`. In the second case, you hand me an index and you get back a `HashMap`.

Comment: @TedHopp very thanks for clearification... your Answer below also helps me alot in some case... i just  need one more help... i want to delete item from listview on button click... how can i done it? i have populated the listview using the method given below by you... thanks in advance Sir..

Comment: @HashirAnwaar - See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click) for how to do that.

Comment: @TeddHopp you rock sir...really helped me as i want... ThumbsUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the extra, it treated your array list as a `Serializable`. You should use:

```
Serializable serialized = intent.getSerializableExtra("saleArrList");
```

Unfortunately, casting this to `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` will generate a compiler warning about unchecked conversions. This is due to how type erasure works in Java. There's no clean and easy way to get rid of this warning. The unclean way is to suppress the warning by putting

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

at the top of your method. This suppresses all unchecked conversion warnings, so it is not particularly safe. However, you can then write:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> saleArrList =
    (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)intent.getSerializableExtra("saleArrList");
```