# setVisibility don't work with addContentView

Tags: android

Here is problem (full function code):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap itemBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache(true));

v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

itemIV = new ImageView(v.getContext());
itemIV.setImageBitmap(itemBitmap);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams ll = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 moveX = v.getX() + 2;
 moveY = v.getY() - 2;

 v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 itemIV.setX(moveX );
 itemIV.setY(movey);

 addContentView(itemIV, ll); //this line stops v.setVisibility(View.GONE) work

 return false;

        }

    });
```

Without addContentView(itemIV, ll); line - setVisibility work fine, after addContentView entering - don't work.

addContentView working fine, setVisibility calling place before or after the addContentView - change nothing

Please help me, i'm really confuse.

Comment: If i understand your code! you are copying bitmap of "v" and then placing bitmap in image view and then in activity. I guess it's not a problem of setVisibility. I think your code is working perfectly.

Comment: post your full function or code

Comment: @HoodVinci I also don't see why setVisibility don't work, if I place imageview..

Comment: How can you say that setvisivility doesn't work ? In fact  you are taking a snapshot of your view and you show it. So how can you say visibility on v is not working ?

Comment: because i steel see 'v' element after v.setVisibility(View.GONE), i see both elements on screen: 'v' an his snapshot 'itemIV'. if i don't add snapshot on a screen - 'v' elelment actually gone after  v.setVisibility(View.GONE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way do not use addContentView, i change it on:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listlay);
linearLayout.addView(itemIV,ll);
```

Result look similar, some problem with placing, but setVisibility work fine, and all listeners work fine (was the problems too)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem but interesting.

The fact is you are calling addContentView from the list listener. So the whole layout refresh. The listView refresh, and your items are reinflated. So your reference to the view v on the method onItemLongClick  is not anymore a reference to a view displayed on the screen.

> **In Summary :**
>   Call to addContentView --> refresh all layout so the ListView too --> your View passed on the calling of onItemClick is no more in the list.

So I see two solutions :

- If you actually want to remove the View/item from the list, do it. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497639/2122876)
- If you don't want to remove it after calling addContentView , try setting for instance a boolean in the object of the list and put the logic on getView of your adpater to show it or not

Comment: Thanks a lot, interesting explanation. Maybe better solution will be not use addContentView to put snapshot on a screen, use some other way, like draw drawableImage. I'm really new in android - just self studding .

Comment: It was not a so common and easy problem, A good challenge ;-). Don't forget to accept the answer if it does the job

Comment: Actually is not clear.. In my code v.setVisibility calling before addContentView, before refreshing all layout.. Why is it don't working?

Comment: In fact this not the same view.  "v" is the view which was clicked.  But by calling addContentView, it causes the whole view to refresh and the listView too. Check behavior of [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). So the "v" of the method context is not anymore, the item view , even if it represents the same underlying data.

Comment: So putting setVisibility before or after addContentView does not change nothing, as you are setting it on v, which is not anymore displayed on the screen.

Comment: Also i check listview and 'v' view codes before and after addContentView calling  -  codes a the same, looks object stays the same after refreshing, but his not react on command

Comment: Yes v is unchanged, this is the problem. v stays the same and is not anymore displayed. Post the code of your adapter i 'll try to be more explicit.

Comment: i use simpleCursorAdapter, nothing special.. I try'd to do 5 sec pause before addContentView  - still without response from setVisibility . Look's problem on compilations stage of running, really some mistik.. how operator which NOT loaded yet can stop other operator running before?? impossible

Comment: If you make a pause it pauses the main UI thread so it can't execute its layout methods. Totally normal. Just make an experiment. Long click on your item  get its  object address (codes). As it's still visible (your problem) , long click again on it. And then you 'll see that's not the same adress object.