# Android delete item from Listview Imlemented Using Baseadapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a adapter with this code:

```
        public class LoadOrders_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private JSONArray data;
private Context context;

public LoadOrders_adapter(JSONArray data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

        return data.length();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    try {
        return data.get(position);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_orderlist, parent, false);

    ImageView product_images=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_images);
    TextView Total_quantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Total_quantity);
    TextView order_status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
    TextView order_date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_date);
    TextView order_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
    TextView product_Name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_Name);

    try {
        JSONObject temp = data.getJSONObject(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(WebConnection.getInstance().resource_url(temp.getString("imgUrl"))).into(product_images);
        Total_quantity.setText(temp.getString("Quantity"));
        order_date.setText(temp.getString("Date_Sub"));
        order_id.setText("#"+temp.getString("Order_ID"));
        order_status.setText(temp.getString("Status"));
        product_Name.setText(temp.getString("Name"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return row;

}
```

}

And a class called:

```
    public class LoadOrders extends ActionBarActivity implements Top_fragment.Top_fragmentListener {

private JSONArray data = null;
private JSONArray OrderDetails2 = null;
private ListView Normal_Orders_list;
private String previous_activity = "info.sliit.mystyle.Home";
private String title_name = "Your Normal Orders";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_promotional_wear);
    Normal_Orders_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Normal_Orders_list);
    new BackgroundProcess().execute();
}

class BackgroundProcess extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoadOrders.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        data = WebConnection.getInstance().get_request("Loading_order_rest/orderloading/user_id/12","json");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        BaseAdapter baseAdapter1 = new LoadOrders_adapter(data,LoadOrders.this);
        Normal_Orders_list.setAdapter(baseAdapter1);
        //Normal_Orders_list.setOnItemClickListener();

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_customized_orders,menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public String get_previous_activity() {
    return previous_activity;
}

@Override
public String getTitle_name() {
    return title_name;
}
```

}

I have an activity called Activity_loading_orders which has a list view called Normal_Orders_list and i have another layout called loading_orderlist which has has a RelativeLayout with some Textviews and a button. As you can see in the code the layout loading_orderlist is loaded as an list item into the Normal_Orders_list activity. What i want to do is to remove list items when the button is clicked see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yia.jpg

My Jason taken from postman

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml><data><datum><Order_ID>8</Order_ID><Quantity>52</Quantity><Comment>fs</Comment><Date_Sub>2015-08-27</Date_Sub><Date_Del/><Product_ID/><Customer_ID>12</Customer_ID><Status>Accepted</Status><View>Unread</View><Name>T-shirt</Name><imgUrl>\assets\images\projectpics\normalt\Edited_front.jpg</imgUrl></datum><datum><Order_ID>10</Order_ID><Quantity>45</Quantity><Comment>sf</Comment><Date_Sub>2015-08-27</Date_Sub><Date_Del/><Product_ID/><Customer_ID>12</Customer_ID><Status>Accepted</Status><View>Unread</View><Name>T-shirt</Name><imgUrl>\assets\images\projectpics\normalt\Edited_front.jpg</imgUrl></datum></data></xml>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the JSON parsing outside of `getView()`. What you're going to want to do is:

1. Have a (preferably) `List` of `<ParsedJsonObject>` (from parsing the JSON) instead of a `JsonArray`
2. On 'cancel' click: delete item at position from the List
3. After deleting the item from the list, notify your adapter that it's dataset has changed: `mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Please note: I'm afraid you're going to have to change to a custom `ArrayAdapter` instead of a `BaseAdapter`. The reason for this is that you are using a `JSONArray` as the data set for the adapter. It's not a good idea to start messing with the JSON yourself, but you're going to have to remove the item from the dataset one way or another. I recommend you take a look at libraries such as [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/).

Those libraries can deserialize JSON into Java objects for you. So what'd you'd end up doing:

1. Fetch JSON data
2. Deserialize JSON data into Java objects, put these objects into a `List<ParsedJsonObject>`
3. Create a new `ArrayAdapter<ParsedJsonObject>`
4. Pass along the list of `ParsedJsonObject`s as the dataset for the `ArrayAdapter` you just created.
5. `getView()` won't have to change a lot, just change where the data comes from. `getView()` lets you know what position you are in, and considering you passed along a `List<ParsedJsonObject>`, you can just do `list.get(position)` to return an object containing all the data.

I hope this helped!

Comment: hello thank you for looking into my problem. But i cant understand what you are saying. Can you just show me how to do it??? Or If there is an easy way other than the methods i have used please let me know.

Comment: Hey just tell me how to do this "Have a (preferably) List of <ParsedJsonObject> (from parsing the JSON) instead of a JsonArray" please help me im really stuck in this place for two days now.

Comment: Like I said, use on the libraries I mentioned to deserialize json into java objects. Genson's really easy.

Comment: i looked into Genson library and added it to my project but i have problems in deserializing here the code:
        Genson genson = new Genson();
        List<Object> MyList = genson.deserialize(how to pass json array      in here???);

Comment: Could you pust the full json you need to parse? I'll help you out when I get home

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me im totally new to android just started 4 days ago. i'll wait till you get home. Thanks Again....

Comment: i posted the full json.

Comment: That's not json, that's XML. Could you post the raw json data?

Comment: what do you mean by raw json data??? is it what i have posted now??? As you can see i call a codeigniter controller and get the return data into a json array

Comment: Json would look like this: {"data":{"datum":[{"Order_ID":"8","Quantity":"52","Comment":"fs","Date_Sub":"2015-08-27","Customer_ID":"12","Status":"Accepted","View":"Unread","Name":"T-shirt","imgUrl":"\\assets\\images\\projectpics\\normalt\\Edited_front.jpg"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

All right, so here's what you need to do:

1. Create new classes: DataModel.java, Data.java, and Datum.java

Put this in them:

DataModel.java:

```
public class DataModel {
    private Data data;

    public Data getData ()
    {
            return data;
    }

    public void setData (Data data)
    {
            this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Data.java:

```
public class Data {
    private Datum[] datum;

    public Datum[] getDatum ()
    {
            return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum (Datum[] datum)
    {
            this.datum = datum;
    }


}
```

Datum.java:

```
public class Datum{
    private String Name;

    private String View;

    private String Status;

    private String Quantity;

    private String Date_Sub;

    private String Comment;

    private String Customer_ID;

    private String Order_ID;

    private String imgUrl;

    public String getName ()
    {
            return Name;
    }

    public void setName (String Name)
    {
            this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String getView ()
    {
            return View;
    }

    public void setView (String View)
    {
            this.View = View;
    }

    public String getStatus ()
    {
            return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus (String Status)
    {
            this.Status = Status;
    }

    public String getQuantity ()
    {
            return Quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity (String Quantity)
    {
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }

    public String getDate_Sub ()
    {
            return Date_Sub;
    }

    public void setDate_Sub (String Date_Sub)
    {
            this.Date_Sub = Date_Sub;
    }

    public String getComment ()
    {
            return Comment;
    }

    public void setComment (String Comment)
    {
            this.Comment = Comment;
    }

    public String getCustomer_ID ()
    {
            return Customer_ID;
    }

    public void setCustomer_ID (String Customer_ID)
    {
            this.Customer_ID = Customer_ID;
    }

    public String getOrder_ID ()
    {
            return Order_ID;
    }

    public void setOrder_ID (String Order_ID)
    {
            this.Order_ID = Order_ID;
    }

    public String getImgUrl ()
    {
            return imgUrl ;
    }

    public void setImgUrl (String imgUrl)
    {
            this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

}
```

And then in your class do `Data d = genson.deserialize(jsonString, DataModel.class);`

Inside DataModel is a Data instance and inside that is your array of datum's