# How to remove a particular row from the listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

Explanation: 
           I know this question asked no. of times. Try to understand my problme first.I have a listview in which i used a BaseAdapter to show dynamic item on my listivew row and it is not a fixed. I delete the data included into the row but deleted the row. While i delete a row it's data removed completely but not a listview row. I want to remove a particular row from the list.

**Adapter**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG=CartAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public Context context;
    public List<CartItems> cartItemList;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public AppCompatActivity activity;

    public CartAdapter(Context context, List<CartItems> cartItemList,AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartItemList = cartItemList;
        this.activity=activity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cartItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.cartItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    private class CartHolder {
        TextView txtItemName, txtItemPrice, txtQtyCount;
        ImageButton btnImgDelete;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final CartHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new CartHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_items, null);

            holder.txtItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            holder.txtItemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_price);
            holder.txtQtyCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_qty_count);

            holder.btnImgDelete=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_img_delete);

            holder.btnImgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to delete item??");
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            cartItemList.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CartHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        CartItems cartItems = cartItemList.get(position);
        holder.txtItemName.setText(cartItems.getItemName());
        holder.txtItemPrice.setText(Util.priceTODollar(cartItems.getItemPrice()));
        holder.txtQtyCount.setText("" + cartItems.getItemQty());


        return view;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot before delete an item from the listview**

[image]

**Screenshot after delete an item from the listview**

[image]

In the second screenshot second item deleted but the white background color remain same.

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: it's already available in my post. In AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: It's about only two lines    cartItemList.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but your code `cartItemList.remove(position);` is wrong, as positions change in ListView, and also Views are reused. You should save the position in the holder.

Comment: so many posts available you can see it in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click

Comment: Actually, holding position in any area will cause issues, as positions change. Rather hold the CartItem in the holder, and then when needed, call remove(item).

Comment: @Surya i used a baseAdapter and i want to delete an item from the baseadapter not from the activity where i pass the List<> value. I don't have an object of the listview in adapter.I must delete an item of the position of the List<>.

Comment: @MilanGajera Put a log inside getCount() to monitor your list contents after the deletion process.

Comment: After deleting an item it decrease the size of the cartItemList.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.After a lot of effort and try. I am not sure it is feasiable solution or not.

After remove an item from the adapter i set the handler and pass the bundler to the Message object like below:

```
holder.btnImgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to delete item??");
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            if(cartItemList.remove(cartItems)) {
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Message message=new Message();
                                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                                bundle.putSerializable("KEY",(Serializable)cartItemList);
                                message.setData(bundle);
                                activity.uiHomeHandler.sendMessage(message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

In activity i again set the cartitemList object to the baseAdapter and calling again it after remove an item

```
SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public class UiHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Bundle b=msg.getData();
            cartItemList=(List)b.getSerializable("KEY");

            mCartAdapter=new CartAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cartItemList,CartActivity.this);
            lvCartItem.setAdapter(mCartAdapter);
            Helper.getListViewSize(lvCartItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
cartItemList.remove(position);
```

As you know for the sake of performance, in list views rows will be [recycled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) as they go off screen. So, when you're initializing a row (where `view == null` in the `getView` method), you actually don't know the position assigned to this row as this row can be assigned multiple different positions.

In order to find the position correctly you should use `getPositionForView` method of the list view. So, in your `onClick` listener replace your code with this one:

```
int p = ((ListView) viewGroup).getPositionForView(view);
cartItemList.remove(p);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note that in the snippet above, `viewGroup` refers to the list view itself and `view` refers to the row being deleted. So, rename the `view` in `onClick` method so that it doesn't cause name-clashing.