# delete item from listview with dialog android

Tags: android, listview, dialog

```
lstv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
lstv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicion, long id) {
                removeItemFromList(posicion);
            }
        });
    }


    protected void removeItemFromList(final int position) {
        final int deletePosition = position;
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Apple.this);
        alert.setTitle("Delete");
        alert.setMessage("¿Do you want delete?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Help here please...!!
            }
        });


        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Which data set you are using to fill your adapter of your listview, array or arraylist ??

Comment: I´m using array list, but i dont sure :/

Comment: Of what thing you are not sure ?

Comment: My listview is the result of a selection in a separate activity , then I want to delete the item with dialog

Comment: Although the result is in separate activity, you are storing your result in array list which you are setting as data source in adapter of listview. Thus, you can use "arrayList.remove(position)" from dialog and update or refresh your listview

Comment: Ohh, I'll try, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass  also the arraylist of item to the function and after you removed you need to run the function `notifyDataSetChanged();` this function re-build the listview.
so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("title...");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                  mArrayList.remove(position);
                  mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497639/5612089)

Modify `arrayList`

and then

```
arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now if required again set `adapter` to the `ListView`

Comment: I have  ArrayList<String> itemList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; like global variables

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your Alert.Dialog methods

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        itemList.remove(favTransPosition);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                         

                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(, , , itemList); // Fill remaining params as you have created earlier
                        lstv.setAdapter(adapter);                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Not jet, i have doubts in the adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(, , , itemList); and i get error in  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you can replace "adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(, , , itemList)" with yours which you have defined above in the code. What error you are getting in adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: just looks in red, i'll try :)