# How to remove an item from an ListView programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have created a ListView in which i display some records from a database. When someone clicks an item from the ListView, i need that item to be removed completely from the ListView. If i use `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` ony the text disappears. I need the entire item to be removed. I am using ListAdapter interface instead of SimpleAdapter class.

How can i do that? Here is my code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, showProductsUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            final String productId = jsonObject.getString("id");
            final String productName = jsonObject.getString("productName");
            HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<>();
            product.put(ID, productId);
            product.put(PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
            productList.add(product);

            String[] from = {ID, PRODUCT_NAME};
            int[] to = {R.id.id, R.id.productName};

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList, R.layout.list_products_to_buy, from, to);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should remove the item from the adapter.

Comment: You are storing the the products in "productList". You should remove the  item you want to remove from that list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically remove items from ListView on a button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click)

Comment: @Alex Ok, and how can i do that?
@sunilsunny I tried to use `productList.remove(position);` and i get thos error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.`

Comment: I also tried to use `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but the notifyDataSetChanged() cannot be used on my listAdapter.

Comment: @Alex M. You need to change your ListAdapter to SimpleAdapter then you can call the notifydatasetchanged method on it after removing the element from your list. Also pls take in consideration what Selvin said in other comments.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you were righ! I used SimpleAdapter in stead of ListAdapter, i added the following code: `productList.remove(position);` and `simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and everything worked fine! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, showProductsUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            final String productId = jsonObject.getString("id");
            final String productName = jsonObject.getString("productName");
            HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<>();
            product.put(ID, productId);
            product.put(PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
            productList.add(product);

            String[] from = {ID, PRODUCT_NAME};
            int[] to = {R.id.id, R.id.productName};

            //NOTE: See I changed it to SimpleAdapter so you can call the notifydatasetchanged method after removing the element from the list.
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList, R.layout.list_products_to_buy, from, to);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   productList.remove(position);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. Thank you so much, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                productList.remove(position);
                listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Obviously will not work if used with filters(fx with ArrayAdapter) ... as position in filtered list would not fit position in unfiltered list ...(that's why we shouldn't also use `productList.get(position)` but rather `parent.getItem(position)` in `onItemClick`)

Comment: I tried to use `listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` but is does not work. Error: `Error:(109, 54) error: cannot find symbol method notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Well you just remove the desired item from the list using the remove() method of your ArrayAdapter.

A possible way to do that would be:

```
Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
```

Comment: I love pirates/thiefs ... exact copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click#answer-5497639) ... **you have enough rep to mark the question as duplicate** why are you copy the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in my case. Do you have any other idea?