# How to remove listview item onresume activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a `MainActivity` with a `ViewPager`. Inside it I have two `tabs` with two `fragments`. Each `fragment` has a `listview`. On clicking the `listview` item, it opens a `DetailsActivity`.

When I delete the `item` from `DetailsActivity` and come back to `MainActivity`, how do I delete the `item` from `listview`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497580/how-to-dynamically-remove-items-from-listview-on-a-button-click

Comment: Where does the listview data come from? A database?

Comment: Data comes from external URL (json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added two `methods` mentioned below to my `fragment`.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()){
        //this allows onResume() to be called only when returning from detailsActivity.
        onResume();

    }
}
```

`setUserVisibleHint` method will be called every time the `fragment` is visible to the user.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
    {
        return;
    }

    //this code will run only when user is returning from detailsActivity       

}
```

Here, code inside `onResume()` method will run only when returning from `detailsActivity`. So I inserted the code to remove list item here.

Answer (score 0):

To remove list item form adapter,

```
arrayList.remove([INDEX]);
```

To refresh listview,

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The adapter is inside viewpager fragment. How do i know the index number to delete?

Answer (score 0):

When you come back from the `DetailsActivity` you might to delete the item from the list. I suppose you have somewhere an adapter with all the items.

```
public void deleteItem(int position){

  arrayList.remove(position);
  notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This inside the adapter.

Comment: How do I know from inside the fragment, when the activity is resumed?

Answer (score 0):

Override OnResume() and notify the adapter

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    doDeleteFromList();
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

When you come back from `DetailsActivity` `OnResume()` of `MainActivity` will get invoked.

Comment: The listview adapter is inside the viewpager fragment. How do i access that adapter from MainActivity

Comment: Please override onResume() of Fragment.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View",
        "Adapter implementation",
        "Simple List View In Android",
        "Create List View Android",
        "Android Example",
        "List View Source Code",
        "List View Array Adapter",
        "Android Example List View"
};


    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values)); //to prevent "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ///..
          //delete item from listView:
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            adapter.remove(itemValue);
```

Comment: This isn't what the question asked. There's no Fragment here

Comment: Delete the ListView element it wants to do.  So I have developed a simple example for this.

Comment: Still, not what the question asked. How do they **get** the position when **returning** from another activity

Comment: "how do I delete the item from listview."
I understand wrong?,sory

Comment: Read the comments on the other posts.