# Removing Values inside BaseAdapter removed always last Value

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have created a ListView for My Model class and displayed it successfully.

I have successfully done removing value/raw from my ListView onItemClickListener of ListView.

It's Ok, But, my ListView also contains an ImageView and I have to delete a row on click of that ImageView.

So, I have taken a BaseAdapter and handle click of my that ImageView inside my BaseAdapter as below :

My Adapter class is as below :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ModelClass> mArrayListModel;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelClass> mArrayListModel) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mArrayListModel = mArrayListModel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayListModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayListModel.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);

            view.textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            view.textAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            // view.btnShow = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
            view.imgDelete=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
            view.textName.setText("" + mArrayListModel.get(position).getStrName());
            view.textAddress.setText("" + mArrayListModel.get(position).getStrAddress());

            convertView.setTag(view);
            view.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+mArrayListModel.get(position).getStrName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mArrayListModel.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView textName, textAddress;
        //Button btnShow;
        ImageView imgDelete;
    }

}
```

I am deleting as below :

```
view.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+mArrayListModel.get(position).getStrName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mArrayListModel.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

The Problem is with deleting item, When I click on ImageView it deletes only last value.. last position from listview. I think its issue with my position.

Will you pls. check it and let me know what might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: When you click on imgDelete at that time you put one toast.In Toast it shows right item value ?

Comment: yes, getting right value...i have added that to check.

Comment: then try this. Instead of notifyDataSetChanged() use notifyItemRemoved(position)

Comment: @shweta ok then i need to remove value from arraylist also ?

Comment: @shweta There is no method as per your suggestion : notifyItemRemoved(position); ..

Comment: @shweta Refer my above comment, there is no such method.

Comment: ya getting. ok let me check

Comment: sorry, that method came in recyclerview. check this may you got your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497639/6021469